# Why My TextField is entering all the characters in Capital, even when I am using the Small characters.How do I make it according to the User

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Enter Thee Name '),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 12,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter Thee PassWord '),
            )
```

[image]

Comment: First thing check your keyboard, does the caps lock is on or not.

Comment: Yes Its off only

Answer (score 0):

It is wierd, because default textCapitalization is none. .. Check your main theme or set `textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none` in your TextField